# Row manipulation in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, gephi

I'm trying to get a csv into a .gexf format file for a dynamic gephi graph. The idea is to have all the parallel edges (edges with the same source and target but different post dates) contained in the attribute data. In the example, all of the dates in the attribute correspond to the posting dates for John answering Jan's question in a discussion forum for an online course.

How do I get a csv looking like this:

```
Jan John    2012-04-07  2012-06-06
Jan Jason   2012-05-07  2012-06-06
Jan John    2012-03-02  2012-06-07
Jan Jason   2012-03-20  2012-06-08
Jan Jack    2012-03-26  2012-06-09
Jan Janet   2012-05-01  2012-06-10
Jan Jack    2012-05-04  2012-06-11
Jan Jason   2012-05-07  2012-06-12
Jan Jack    2012-05-09  2012-06-13
Jan John    2012-05-15  2012-06-14
Jan Janet   2012-05-15  2012-06-15
Jan Jason   2012-05-20  2012-06-16
Jan Jack    2012-05-23  2012-06-17
Jan Josh    2012-05-25  2012-06-18
Jan Jack    2012-05-28  2012-06-19
Jan Josh    2012-06-01  2012-06-20
```

into a format looking like this:

```
<edge source="Jan" target="John" start="2012-02-20" end="2012-06-06" weight="1" id="133">
        <attvalues>
          <attvalue for="0" value="1" start="2012-04-07" end="2012-06-06"/>
          <attvalue for="0" value="2" start="2012-06-06" end="2012-06-06"/>
          <attvalue for="0" value="3" start="2012-06-06" end="2012-06-06"/>
        </attvalues>
 </edge>
<next edge...
</next edge>
```

The way I've attempted this is not working out so well. I've tried to create two lists, and for each entry in the first list, search to find a match of the first two entries in the second list. If there's a match, then my script would delete the row in the second list and append the pair of dates.  With each row representing the complete number of correspondences between a questioner and an answerer, I would then write a script to convert the row into the edge / attribute data. I've been using [this as some sort of guide](http://andreew.userpage.fu-berlin.de/ruby/picon.txt).

Comment: well, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Where do the `start` and `end` dates come from? I can't tell what the question is.

Comment: I fail to see the corelation between "John" and the dates in the target. Please clarify

Comment: ...and where does ""2007-01-22" come from? Is it a fixed string present in all edges?

Comment: I would have used [string templates](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#template-strings) for this. Parse out the data using the [csv-module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html), put it in a dictionary and use template to make the substitution. Good luck and please update your question with some code if you are stuck and we'd gladly help! Lots of examples in the provided links to get you started...

Comment: Looking into these string templates now! Apologize for failure to elaborate. Thanks, and will definitely continue posting as I plug away.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Python pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) project, which is designed to simplify this kind of operation. An example of how it can group and parse your data....

```
# Load your CSV as a pandas 'DataFrame'.
In [13]: df = pd.read_csv('your file', names=['source', 'target', 'start', 'end'])

# Look at the first few rows. It worked.
In [14]: df.head()
Out[14]: 
  source target       start         end
0    Jan  Jason  2012-05-07  2012-06-06
1    Jan   John  2012-03-02  2012-06-07
2    Jan  Jason  2012-03-20  2012-06-08
3    Jan   Jack  2012-03-26  2012-06-09
4    Jan  Janet  2012-05-01  2012-06-10

# Group the rows by the the name columns. Each unique pair gets its own group.
In [15]: edges = df.groupby(['source', 'target'])

In [16]: for (source, target), edge in edges: # consider each unique name pair an edge
    print source, target
    for _, row in edge.iterrows(): # loop through all the rows belonging to these names
        print row['start'], row['end']
   ....:         
Jan Jack
2012-03-26 2012-06-09
2012-05-04 2012-06-11
2012-05-09 2012-06-13
2012-05-23 2012-06-17
2012-05-28 2012-06-19
Jan Janet
2012-05-01 2012-06-10
2012-05-15 2012-06-15
Jan Jason
2012-05-07 2012-06-06
2012-03-20 2012-06-08
2012-05-07 2012-06-12
2012-05-20 2012-06-16
Jan John
2012-03-02 2012-06-07
2012-05-15 2012-06-14
Jan Josh
2012-05-25 2012-06-18
2012-06-01 2012-06-20
```

All that remains is to elaborate on those print statements with your XML, and possibly output to a file instead of printing.

Comment: Thanks Dan! This seems incredibly useful. I will begin playing with it.

Comment: It works on all platforms. I use it on a Mac, too. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#all-platforms

Comment: Is this available for Mac? I tried running `pip install pandas` and I get `failed with error code 1`

Comment: Without a more specific error, I'm not sure how to help you. I installed and used this on a couple Macs. If pip isn't working, a search for "install pandas Mac" on StackOverflow turns up many threads that discuss alternatives. I believe there is a binary online somewhere, like there is for Windows, but I can't find it either. @Jeff?

Comment: @goldisfine u need to install numpy and cython before installing pandas